# Flag suggestion: Not a question

Tags: feature-request, flags

Sometimes, new posters will post something as a question that isn't quite spam nor a poorly written question (nor fish nor flesh nor good red herring), but is in fact not a question at all. It may be a code dump or an attempt to chat.

There is a "Not an answer" flag for things posted as answers that are not, but there doesn't seem to be anything analogous to raise for things posted as questions that are not questions (and therefore not poorly written questions) or commercial spam.

Comment: close => off topic => "Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No new flag type is needed.

If a question isn't asking anything*, you can flag or vote to close it as "unclear what you're asking" (now labeled "needs details or clarity"), or a variety of other possibly applicable reasons.

If a question is simply commercial spam, you can flag it as spam.

---

<sub>*Note that I said "isn't asking anything", not "doesn't have a question mark". We're humans; we can infer a question from some statements. Don't vote like a robot.</sub>

Comment: And if none of the standard reasons fit, there's an "Other" option where you can fill in any comment you want.

Comment: This is just about the only time you won't get into trouble for a snarky response (saying "it's unclear what you're asking" to mean "it's clear you aren't actually asking a question" is as sarcastic as it gets).